# Плагин для доводки блоков при скроле

Tags: javascript, reactjs, прокрутка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите плагин для react который при скроле доводил блоки до верха или низа в зависимости куда скролим. Блоки есть с большим контентом (такие блоки к примеру если мы скролим блок, поднимался до конца вверх и включался обычный скрол чтоб просмотреть контент)